# How to leverage an FTP Task to capture the name of the file it downloads?

Tags: c#, ssis

I have an FTP Task in my SSIS package.

In the task editor I have set my RemotePath to look for the following file to download:

```
/incoming/MyFile*.xml
```

Clients will routinely drop xml files and I inserted the Kleene operator (*) because the convention is to append a date to the file name.

After the FTP Task downloads a file, I have to write the FileName and CreationDate properties to a table using a Execute SQL task.

The problem is, when I download a file, I dont have a way to get access to those properties on the file as I have no way to reference the name of the File I am downloading.

Is there a way to leverage the FTP Task to capture the full name of the file it downloads?

I think if I at least had the specific name, then I could use a script task to encapsulate the file in a FileInfo object.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the files to an empty folder, you can then use the foreach component to iterate through the filenames in that folder. Check the following link to see how to do such a task:

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-configure-foreach-loop-file.html

Comment: But even with this solution, which I am already doing programatically within a script task using linq, doesn't let me isolate the file name as the file is being downloaded in the FTP task. Thats what I am really after.

Answer (score 2):

If you skip the FTP task altogether and use a [script task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd129901%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to perform the [FTP](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/2b7cf6b5-d16d-44cd-954d-68e9ba98ee91/), you can set the exact name of the file you're FTP'ing to a package variable. If you're receiving multiple files and can't drop them into an empty folder as @cfrag advocates, then I'd build an in-memory XML document with the files and then shred it with a [Foreach Nodelist Enumerator](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2009/02/foreach-nodelist-enumerator.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can’t get the file name because the task will get all the files in one go.
What you can do is use the foreachloop container as the other user advised, BUT, I would add another step before to avoid concurrency problems like, for example, imagine that you copy all your files to your destination folder and while you are looping through them, you (or someone else for some reason) runs the package again before the loop is over. You will end up with duplications.

To avoid that, I suggest that you create a new folder inside your destination folder for each run. I’ve done this once and it not hard, just create a package variable called DestFolder and In the properties pane for the File connection manager (where you have your destination folder configured), expand the Expressions by clicking the ellipse and on the expression builder window set the “Expression” as:

```
"c:\\Destination_folder\\" + @[User::DestFolder]
```

And before your FTP task, set the DestFolder variable with the name of the folder for that particular execution.

After you copied the file, then loop trough them with no worries.

FYI, if you have to create the destination folders, it’s very simple, [here](http://sqlserversolutions.blogspot.com/2009/01/creating-directory-using-ssis.html) is an article to help you with that.

Comment: I had a feeling when the package kicks off that dupes would happen. Thanks for the heads up.